hazelcast FencedLock owner
We are using an implementation of leader election that is based in FencedLock. One thing that we would like to be able to achieve is to tell which member is now the owner.
Essentially, we have leader election for IScheduledExecutorService that is started on multiple nodes and we want only a single one to execute it. One at a time that is.
In the actuator spring endpoint, we would like to be able to output which member where the IScheduledExecutorService is running is the current owner. Something like :
current owner is : <MEMBER_HERE>
It looks like HZ is able to tell that, from the logs :
Created new session: 13 in CPGroupId{name='snapshot-fetcher', seed=0, groupId=244} for SERVER -> [OUR_HOST_HERE]:5701

but is there an API to achieve the same?

while the question might be interesting, it is of no point to us.
Hazelcast 5.5 will make CPSubsystem an enterprise only feature, and the leader election process that we use (based on FancedLock) is now pointless.

That is an unfortunate decision of the company
